# how to update video custom_lables with Facebook Graph API POST request

Tags: javascript, java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add custome_labels to my video using facebook graph api.

I'm trying to use the following :

```
FB.api(
  '/{Video_ID}',
  'POST',
  {"custom_labels":"TEST"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

The Error I'm Facing is :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) param custom_labels must be an array.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
  }
}
```

Any Idea how to fix this please ? Thank you !

Comment: {"custom_labels":  ["TEST"] },

Comment: i tried ["TEST"] and got this error ( even though i added all the required permissions ) :

message: '(#200) Permissions error', 
type: 'OAuthException', 
code: 200

Comment: it feels that permission are checked after model validation, thought the original error is resolved, permission is a different issue

Comment: I'm guessing you are probably not using a page access token there, but just your user token.

Comment: Hello , Thank you for the replies. I'm actually using the page access token.